# Can map function replace the original data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have three variables RR1234, RR5678, RR0135:

```
RR1234   <- rnorm(100, 2, 3)
RR5678    <-  rnorm(100,3,4)
RR0135    <- rnorm(100,4,5)  
x   <- data.frame(RR1234,RR5678,RR0135)
```

I have a function to trim `x`:

```
done   <- function(x){
   x[x > 1] = NA
   return(x)
}
```

I want to trim `RR1234` and `RR5678`:

```
c(x$RR1234,x$RR5678) %>% map(done)
```

but the data in `x` remains the same.

I also tried:

```
x   <-  x %>%  select(RR1234,RR5678) %>% map(done)
```

Though the first two variables works well, but the third one `RR0135` is gone.

Is there any convenient way to replace the two variables in `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through what you tried:

```
c(x$RR1234,x$RR5678) %>% map(done)
```

This does an operation on `x`, but will not change the contents of `x`. The contents of `x` will not change unless you assign the operation back to `x`.

```
x   <-  x %>%  select(RR1234,RR5678) %>% map(done)
```

This line of code does change `x`, but the `select` verb from `dplyr` means that you are only including those two columns. Other columns have been discarded from the operation. If you want to change those two columns and not the third, you can do that. Here are two ways. Neither uses `map()`.

```
# Generate the data using set.seed to make it reproducible
set.seed(1)
RR1234   <- rnorm(100, 2, 3)
RR5678    <-  rnorm(100,3,4)
RR0135    <- rnorm(100,4,5)  
x   <- data.frame(RR1234,RR5678,RR0135)
```

Using base R functionality, you can assign new values to data.frame columns using the `$` to subset without changing anything else. This works with any other type of subset.

```
# base R
x$RR1234 <- done(x$RR1234)
x$RR5678 <- done(x$RR5678)
```

Using `dplyr` version 1.0 or greater, you can use the following. The `mutate(across(...))` construction allows you to change multiple columns bases on passing criteria and functions to `across`.

```
x %>% mutate(across(c("RR1234", "RR5678"), done))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `across()` from `dplyr`. And as you want to transform some variables, it is better to use `mutate()`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
RR1234   <- rnorm(100, 2, 3)
RR5678    <-  rnorm(100,3,4)
RR0135    <- rnorm(100,4,5)  
x   <- data.frame(RR1234,RR5678,RR0135)
#Function
done   <- function(x){
  x[x > 1] = NA
  return(x)
}
#Code
x2 <- x %>%  mutate(across(RR1234:RR5678,~done(.)))
```

Output:

```
         RR1234     RR5678      RR0135
1    0.94194089         NA  13.0713017
2   -0.33647069 -2.3019341   9.4639157
3            NA -0.5368949  -6.4242588
4            NA         NA   4.4593853
5            NA         NA   0.6853094
6            NA         NA   7.6834331
7            NA         NA   1.8147963
8   -0.41588192         NA   9.3598014
9    0.76115066         NA  10.8331170
10           NA         NA   4.7973967
11           NA -2.3059266  -7.7575549
12           NA         NA   1.8152209
13           NA         NA  -0.9860351
14           NA         NA  12.1584945
15  -2.24455694  0.6763838  -4.2775746
16           NA         NA  -0.4178979
17           NA         NA  11.2213595
18           NA         NA  -2.2960382
19           NA         NA   0.3525616
20           NA -2.0038667   2.9802946
21           NA  0.7472525   4.0493003
22           NA         NA  13.6511832
23           NA         NA   6.5547820
24           NA -2.2045896   1.2317368
25  -0.62548661 -0.8736796   0.5770349
26           NA  0.4075356   9.2716612
27           NA         NA   4.1747139
28           NA         NA  -7.3872696
29   0.94287484 -8.0979632   0.5209943
30           NA -3.9503837   4.1438962
31  -2.74859617         NA   4.0467313
32           NA         NA   9.4205472
33           NA         NA -10.1071739
34           NA         NA  13.7521859
35  -1.15968127         NA  -4.0899815
36           NA         NA   7.7387901
37  -2.45832478         NA  -5.6710160
38  -3.09780799 -2.4786657  -4.1983864
39           NA         NA   8.0691432
40   0.44259503         NA  -2.4539690
41           NA         NA  -4.2937684
42           NA         NA  -3.4187835
43  -1.67688948         NA   5.2468200
44           NA  0.1528275  -6.1676265
45           NA         NA   6.5787688
46           NA         NA   1.2673593
47  -5.77722184         NA   6.7476928
48  -0.71438036 -0.6985110   1.1490648
49  -2.69295812         NA   2.7580518
50           NA         NA   6.7804525
51           NA         NA  -1.0621607
52           NA         NA   3.7175144
53           NA         NA   6.3843942
54           NA         NA   8.3657269
55  -1.46609589         NA  -2.5650315
56           NA -9.7247597  -1.0451021
57           NA         NA  11.2932211
58  -0.38620085         NA   6.5005979
59           NA         NA   2.5991516
60  -0.63715413         NA   2.9463852
61   0.12413129 -0.2764512  13.8596677
62           NA -3.5446673  -0.5171467
63           NA         NA   3.9371540
64  -0.31371041         NA   8.9294396
65  -1.18244591         NA   8.4827556
66  -4.83866907         NA   3.9618274
67           NA         NA  10.1643994
68  -0.75624474         NA  -3.2039191
69  -3.62029427         NA  -1.8827352
70           NA         NA   3.3186486
71           NA -2.9736113   4.0444030
72           NA         NA   5.6982921
73  -1.35997829  0.9391924   4.2699128
74  -3.48608075         NA  -2.0635431
75  -6.89075863 -5.9582709   0.4530760
76           NA  0.2738838  -3.4495561
77  -4.11640879 -1.6386795   8.9934335
78  -4.49512380         NA  -4.5578025
79  -2.66125238 -2.1222533   1.7672672
80           NA  0.3992611   1.6496420
81           NA         NA  -4.8627943
82  -0.41373126 -3.4452060  -2.9630815
83  -1.74671667         NA   2.0555012
84  -0.58334242         NA   6.2798613
85           NA         NA   2.1313488
86           NA         NA  15.9778175
87  -1.08969338         NA  -5.5826951
88           NA -2.4728756   4.6548008
89           NA -5.0936805  10.6863344
90           NA         NA   6.3066017
91           NA         NA   3.7410041
92           NA         NA  -4.8135729
93           NA         NA   9.3064735
94  -0.04695171         NA   4.4903433
95           NA         NA  11.7926356
96           NA         NA   4.7113170
97  -4.08935228         NA   7.9562516
98           NA         NA  13.9372643
99           NA         NA   1.6008497
100          NA         NA   5.4534442
```

Comment: One additional option: `done()` can be accomplished inline with `if_else()`: `mutate(x, across(c("RR1234", "RR5678"), ~if_else(. > 1, NA_real_, .)))`

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that you are using `purrr::map` and the magrittr/tidyverse pipe `%>%` but are unfamiliar with `dplyr::mutate` since the two packages are usually taught together, with `dplyr` taught first.

```
dplyr::mutate(x, across(c(RR1234, RR5678), done))
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree that `mutate`/`across` is the best idiom here.  Given that OP specifically asked about `purrr::map`, here is a `map` solution:

```
set.seed(123)

as.list(colnames(x)) %>%
  setNames(colnames(x)) %>%
  map_dfc(function(col) if_else(x[col] > 1, NA_real_, pull(x[col])))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
    RR1234 RR5678  RR0135
     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.319   0.158 NA     
 2 NA      NA     NA     
 3 NA      NA     NA     
 4 NA      NA     NA     
 5 NA      -0.806 NA     
 6 NA      NA     NA     
 7 NA      -0.140  0.0570
 8 -1.80   -3.67  NA     
 9 -0.0606 NA     NA     
10  0.663  NA     NA     
# … with 90 more rows
```